Minimal Regularity Conditions for Arbitrary Precise Approximation of Convex Bodies by Polygons and Polyhedra in Hausdorff Distance
I was reading the proof of Archimedes, where he demonstrates that the area of a circle is equal to that of a right triangle whose legs are the radius of the circle and half its circumference. In his proof, Archimedes utilizes the fact that a circle can be approximated by a regular polygon with arbitrary precision.
Now I am interested in understanding the general conditions under which a convex body can be approximated arbitrarily closely by polygons (in $\mathbb{R}^2$) or polyhedra (in $\mathbb{R}^3$) with respect to the Hausdorff distance.
While I assume that rectifiability of the boundary is a necessary condition, I seek to identify any additional properties required to ensure that such approximations are possible. Specifically:

Sufficiency of Compactness and Continuity:

Is it sufficient for the boundary to be compact and merely continuous ($C^0$-smooth) to allow for arbitrary precise approximation by polygons or polyhedra?


Necessity of Higher Smoothness:

Or is a higher degree of smoothness, such as $C^1$-smoothness (which ensures the existence of tangent and normal planes at boundary points), necessary for the approximation by polygons/polyhedra with arbitrary precision?


Minimal Regularity Requirements:

What are the minimal regularity conditions on the boundary of a convex body that enable such approximations? Are there specific theorems or results in geometric approximation theory that address this?



